# Check config/assets are published or not in Laravel package

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, package, laravel-5.4

I have two questions which are quite related.

1) I'm building a Laravel package which will have a package config file. It can be published using `php artisan vendor:publish` command. Now in the service provider class of that package, I want to know that if that file has been published by the user or not. How can I do that? By simply checking file existence or is there any Laravel specific way for that?

2) In the view file of that package, I want to include a js file which is also there in that same package. How can I do that? Do I have to publish it first into Laravel's public directory and then include it? If possible I don't want to publish it.

Let me know if anything is not clear.

Thanks